# SVN Feature Branch Method

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, repository

I am getting a SVN server setup and will be using the feature branch method. I plan on having 1+ branches making up a release tag. How do I merge (?) multiple branches into the release tag, while still maintaining diffs and such? I've given an example of our workflow below.

Multiple devs pull to local
Create feature branch
Commit to branch
Use branch to build QA
(Here is where my question starts)
I need to have all the branches for the next build to be put into a build tag to be used to build Production

Comment: Technically, your question never started.

Answer (score 2):

Why not merge each feature branch back into the trunk?  After trunk has enough features to justify a new version then create a new branch off of the trunk to start preparing that version for a release.  Once you have the version branch ready for a new release then create a new tag.

Answer (score 1):

Merge to trunk, then tag.

Please see [Using TortoiseSVN how do I merge changes from the trunk to a branch and vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299142/using-tortoisesvn-how-do-i-merge-changes-from-the-trunk-to-a-branch-and-vice-vers)