# Can I (and how to) apply a patch created from trunk to a branch?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, branch, patch, trunk

I was working on the trunk recently and the changed I did I thought others might need them so I created a patch just before committing.

Now a fellow dev who was working on a branch (which comes from the trunk a couple of weeks back) needs those changes to go on a new server.

I'm trying to apply my patch with Tortoise SVN but it does'nt seam to like the disparities of my working copies. I have :

- My trunk at : D:\SVN\Trunk
- The branch at : D:\SVN\Branches\TheBranchINeedToPatch

Am I trying to do something impossible ? Is there something I'm missing ?

Can I apply a trunk patch to a branch working copy ?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perquisite: Let's say you are currently working on the branch. To check that use `svn info`. The url should be pointing to your branch

Then you can merge the changes from trunk to your branch by using merge command

```
svn merge -r FROM_REVISION:REQUIRED_REVISION url/to/trunk .
or
svn merge -r 26:32 url/to/trunk .
```

This will bring all change sets from rev 26 to 32 of trunk into your branch.

Ah, there already is a discussion on how to do this with TortoiseSVN:  [Using TortoiseSVN how do I merge changes from the trunk to a branch and vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299142/using-tortoisesvn-how-do-i-merge-changes-from-the-trunk-to-a-branch-and-vice-vers)

Comment: +1, merge when you want to get something to a different branch.

Comment: Ok thanks, I merged my trunk onto my branch selecting the specific revisions. Thanks for the help!

Comment: OK, how can I do that **without** having access to trunk? User who has the access to trunk only gave me the **patch** he created for trunk.

Comment: @izogfif I don't understand. You want to apply a patch to /trunk and you don't have Read / Write access?

Comment: This worked for me although I noted that changes that resulted in revision '26' are NOT included.  IE: Rev 26 should correspond to the current 'state' of the target branch.