# How to update file in SVN branch with file from trunk?

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn, branch

I've been working on a branch of a project for a few months now. I'm about to move onto a new task in the branch and it would be ideal if I could update some particular files in the branch with the last updates from the trunk. Essentially, updating a part of the branch with the latest versions from the trunk. This should then make it easier for the branch merge when the branch development is completed.

Can this be done in SVN? If so, how? I'm using SVN 1.7.8 (linux,server) and tortoiseSVN (windows,client)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I understand correctly, you *should* have been merging changes on the trunk into your branch regularly over the entire lifetime of the branch - this makes it less traumatic and reduces the number of file merges required.

TortoiseSVN has the tools to do this. IIRC (I don't have it installed at the moment) just select the Merge option from the menu.

Comment: Your right, managed to find the full steps on how to do this on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/299142/using-tortoisesvn-how-do-i-merge-changes-from-the-trunk-to-a-branch-and-vice-ver